# SalesForce SOSL Search - How to query related Objects over REST (Objects: Case, Contact)

Tags: rest, api, salesforce

I'd like to query a list of case numbers and print the related contact information in one single SOSL search command. Is this doable by use of SOSL over REST API to use ID fields as pointer?

**Sample Search**

```
"find {XY00001234*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Case(ContactEmail,OwnerId WHERE ContactEmail LIKE '%.test'), Contact(Email WHERE Id = Case.OwnerId) LIMIT 10"
```

The query above throws an error like: "Bind variables only allowed in Apex code".

Answer (score 0):

SOSL is built for speed with indexing in mind. I would advise only returning the needed fields like Id and then doing a seperate SOQL Query for all other data from the Id's returned by SOSL.